# Power on issue - system starts/stops/starts 4 - 5 times before full start

Tags: boot, drivers

When I turn on my system, it will run through a start, stop, start sequence 4 to 5 times before a full power up. Any ideas what is causing this? System details are: AMD 1700x, ASRock 350 Pro4 mother board, EVGA GE Force GTX 1050 graphics card, Corsair 750W power supply, 256 ssd where Ubuntu is loaded, Corsair 16G ram.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Mike

Comment: update your question with any red errors you see in output of running `dmesg` from a terminal

Comment: Have you checked at whether all the peripherals being initialised first before, it could as well be the case of some USB not being initialised or your boot order is set to something else instead of 1st boot priority or PSU not being able to provide adequate supply?
You need to be more clear with steps you took/tried etc before expecting an answer.

Comment: Shaze, I'll be honest, aside from installing Ubuntu 16.04, I have not taken any other steps aside from this one to determine what is causing this issue. Scott, thanks for the tip regarding the dmesg log. There are no red errors but there were certain run error comments scattered throughout the log. I'm not sure which, if any, would shed some light on the problem.